# Get free space from multiple computers

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-3.0, diskspace, export-csv

I wrote a simple script which should get a list of computers from an OU and report on disk size and free space amount on each reachable machine.

```bsh
$computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=test,ou=test,dc=test,dc=test,dc=net" -Filter * | select -ExpandProperty Name

$output = Foreach ($item in $computers) {
    Write-host $item    
    $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $item -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"
    $disk_size = [math]::Round($disk.Size/1GB,2)
    Write-host $disk_size
    $disk_freespace = [math]::Round($disk.Freespace/1GB,2)
    Write-Host $disk_freespace
}

$output | Export-Csv "networkpath\free_space_on_c_drive.csv" -notypeinformation -encoding "unicode"
```

The output looks good on screen but the exported CSV file is empty. I guess that I could change `foreach` to `ForEach-Object` but I don't think that it's good practice to put every script to one liner and in case I need to add more actions then it will be painful.

Here is my updated code based on the comments:

```bsh
$computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "ou=t,ou=test,ou=Production,ou=test,dc=test,dc=test,dc=net" -Filter * | select -ExpandProperty Name
$output = Foreach ($item in $computers) {
    $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $item -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"
    $disk_size = [math]::Round($disk.Size/1GB,2)
    $disk_freespace = [math]::Round($disk.Freespace/1GB,2)
    $output = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = $item
        Size = $disk_size
        FreeSpace    = $disk_freespace
    }
}

$output | Export-Csv "networkpath\$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_free_space_on_c_drive.csv" -notypeinformation -encoding "unicode"
```

But now I'm getting only one record in my CSV file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you never send the values to the `$Output` variable. `Write-Host` ONLY writes to the screen, not to the pipeline ... and that means your $var is empty. [*grin*] remove the `W-H` calls, build a `PSCustomObject`, and send that to your `$Output` variable.

Comment: "I don't think that it's good practice to put every script to one liner" - Why not?  You could certainly rewrite this code using a single pipeline, but that doesn't mean it has to be written on one line.  In fact, as written this won't query a single computer until _all_ matching computers have first been collected in `$computers`, and won't write a single record to the CSV file until _all_ records have been collected in `$output`.  So, by not using a pipeline this will consume more memory and have a delay before each step can proceed.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I've edited my post to latest changes, but seems something is still wrong.

Comment: @Bacon, I will try to rewrite this using pipeline but would like to make work the current one.

Comment: [1] put the `$Output` variable outside the loop. like this ... `$Output = foreach (){}` and then put the PSCO all on its own so that it gets sent out to `$Output`. ///// [2] where is the code that sends things to the CSV?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Code that sends things to the CSV is still there. In the end as in my first example outside the loop.

Comment: @DmitryDorofeev - PLEASE use complete, concise code samples. your 2nd sample is missing parts that are important. please post the actual code ...

Comment: The first code snippet in the question only required changes _inside_ the loop to make it work; everything else should have stayed the same.  You removed the `$output = ` from `$output = Foreach ($item in $computers) {`.  Also, remove the `$output += ` from `$output += [PSCustomObject]@{` so that `PSCustomObject` will be yielded to whatever is collecting the output of the loop, which is `$output` in this case.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Edited, I've left only final version with your latest comments.

Comment: @BACON Edited the code according to your comment regarding the `$output` variable. Let's see if it works for me. Final version is posted now.

Comment: No, you changed `+=` to `=`.  You need to remove `$output += ` completely so that entire line is `[PSCustomObject]@{`.  Again, you don't want anything inside the loop to "capture" that `PSCustomObject`.  That will allow it to "bubble up" outside the loop where `$output = foreach ...` will capture it.  By the way, you should probably keep two code snippets in your question: the original and the work-in-progress.  Without the original this question won't make sense to future readers.

Comment: Finally it works as I expected.

Comment: @Bacon Thank you for all your patience and assistance.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you too for all your patience and assistance.

Comment: @DmitryDorofeev - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what i was trying to convey about building a `PSCustomObject` & sending that out to a collection. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- fakes reading in a text file
  when ready to do this with your data, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block and use `Get-Content` OR use `Get-ADComputer`.
- defines the report file name
- defines what to use when there is no response
- iterates thru the computer name collection
- tests to see if the target responds
- if yes = gets the WMI disk data
  this uses a `splat` for readability instead of a long line of parameters & values.
- if no = sets the values to `$NoResponse`
- builds the `PSCO`
- sends that out to the `$Results` collection
- shows that on screen
- sends the collection to the report file

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$ComputerList = @'
BetterNotBeThere
LocalHost
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a CSV file

$TimeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$ReportPath = $env:TEMP
$ReportFile = 'Dmitry Dorofeev_-_DiskSpaceReport_-_{0}.csv' -f $TimeStamp
$FullReportFile = Join-Path -Path $ReportPath -ChildPath $ReportFile

$NoResponse = '__n/a__'

$Results = foreach ($CL_Item in $ComputerList)
    {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $CL_Item -Count 2 -Quiet)
        {
        $GWO_Params = @{
            Class = 'Win32_LogicalDisk'
            ComputerName = $CL_Item
            Filter = "DeviceID = 'c:'"
            }
        $DiskInfo = Get-WmiObject @GWO_Params
        $Size_GB = [math]::Round($DiskInfo.Size / 1gb, 2)
        $FreeSpace_GB = [math]::Round($DiskInfo.FreeSpace / 1gb, 2)
        }
        else
        {
        $Size_GB = $FreeSpace_GB = $NoResponse
        }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $CL_Item
        Size_GB = $Size_GB
        FreeSpace_GB = $FreeSpace_GB
        }
    }

# display on screen
$Results

# send to a csv file
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath $FullReportFile -NoTypeInformation
```

on screen output ...

```
ComputerName     Size_GB FreeSpace_GB
------------     ------- ------------
BetterNotBeThere __n/a__ __n/a__
LocalHost        931.41  730.79
10.0.0.1         __n/a__ __n/a__
127.0.0.1        931.41  730.79
```

csv file [`C:\Temp\Dmitry Dorofeev_-_DiskSpaceReport_-_2020-05-22.csv`] content ...

```
"ComputerName","Size_GB","FreeSpace_GB"
"BetterNotBeThere","__n/a__","__n/a__"
"LocalHost","931.41","730.79"
"10.0.0.1","__n/a__","__n/a__"
"127.0.0.1","931.41","730.79"
```